# How do I output content to a HttpServletResponse buffer?

Tags: spring, servlets, junit, httpresponse, mockmvc

I'm using Spring 4.3.8.RELEASE.  I want to set an error message for a particular Forbidden error.  I have this in my controller.  "response" is of the type "javax.servlet.HttpServletResponse".

```
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
        response.setContentLength(errorMsg.length());
        byte[] buffer = new byte[10240];
        final OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
        output.write(buffer, 0, errorMsg.length());
        output.flush();
```

However, the content doesn't seem to be getting returned, at least I can't see it in my unit test ...

```
    final MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(get(contextPath + "/myurl") 
                    .contextPath(contextPath)
                    .principal(auth)
                    .param("param1", param1)
                    .param("param2", param2))
        .andExpect(status().isForbidden())
        .andReturn();
    // Verify the error message is correct
    final String msgKey = "error.code";
    final String errorMsg = MessageFormat.format(resourceBundle.getString(msgKey), new Object[] {});
    Assert.assertEquals("Failed to return proper error message.", errorMsg, result.getResponse().getContentAsString());
```

The assertion failed saying that the response string was empty.  What is teh proper way to write the response back to the HttpServletResponse buffer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never write `errorMsg` to `output` or `buffer`.

Something like

```
response.getWriter().write(errorMsg)
```

should fix the issue

Comment: Yes I do.  See the line -- "output.write(buffer, 0, errorMsg.length());"

Comment: No, that writes `errorMsg.length()` bytes starting from 0 from `buffer` to output. However `buffer` is all 0 because you never copied `errorMsg` to it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the response entity

```
@RequestMapping("/handle")
public ResponseEntity<String> handle() {

   HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
   responseHeaders.setLocation(location);
   responseHeaders.set("MyResponseHeader", "MyValue");
   return new ResponseEntity<String>("Hello World", responseHeaders, HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
 }
```

[Spring Response Entity](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html)

Comment: Maybe I shoudl have been more clear.  How do I generate an output string given an HttpSErvletResponse.  Your answer doesn't address this.  Thanks, -

Answer (score 0):

A good thing would be to `throw` a custom exception passing the `HttpServletResponse` as an argument or using one of already existing exceptions (if it serves your use case) so that way the error is handled outside of the controller method (separate concerns, considered a good practice).

If not, you can set the response directly in controller method.

So in both cases you can use `HttpServletResponse`s `sendError` method, like so:

```
// your controller (or exception) method
    try {
        response.sendError(HttpStatus.FORBIDEN.value(), "My custom error message")
        } catch (IOException e) {
    // handle if error could not be sent
        }
    }
```

This will print out a string as a response with desired `HttpStatus`.

Also, here is some 'oldie-but-goldie' info on Spring Exception handling [here](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc)

Comment: THanks.  How do I verify this in my JUnit test code?  I put in your code and although I can see it getting run during debugging, the line "Assert.assertEquals("Failed to return proper error message.", errorMsg, result.getResponse().getContentAsString());" fails complaining that "result.getResponse().getContentAsString()" is empty.

Comment: @Dave if you are using `@RestController`, you read from a JSON response. So use `mockMvc.perform(.....)
   .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
   .andExpect(jsonPath("$.error.message").value("My custom error message"));` You can see the json structure by making a call via Postman or such